# How to perform analysis on point datasets in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3

I'm new with ArcGIS and currently I'm working on a project involving CAFO waste storage type, land cover, and Nitrate levels in Northern Missouri. I have land cover as a raster data set, with six different values indicating terrain. Nitrate level is represented by point data split into ranges. CAFO type is split into 3 different values. I'm trying to "perform analysis" on CAFO type with Nitrate level. They are both point data sets and I'm really just trying to relate them. Any suggestions?

Nitrate (mg/L):
0-.25, .30-1.0, 1.1-1.9, 2.0-9.9, >10

CAFOs: Storage Lagoon, Underfloor Pits, No Storage

Main attributes for land cover are forest, pasture, and open water.

I'm trying to see if there's any correlation between higher Nitrate levels and a specific storage type (for example, if Storage Lagoons are associated with higher Nitrate levels). Is there any analysis function that would provide me with this information? I could also relate land cover to Nitrate levels, but I think it might be more complicated stepping outside of the point-to-point.

Here's a photo of what I've got so far, I know, it's a mess...
[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample of each dataset and also outline the type of analysis you are trying to perform.  As it stands your question is rather vague.

Comment: What is the maximum surrounding distance you would consider for each facility based on the distribution of the two point sets?  Depending on the distance, it sounds like you also need to consider elevation, since it unlikely that a facility could contribute to Nitrate concentrations at higher elevations than the facility.  Gravity plumes do not necessarily spread out in a circle around a facility, so a simple distance tolerance might not match reality.